# how to merge rows of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I tried fetching tables from a pdf using tabula and got the dataframe like this

```
   Crop(Varieties)                             Crop Specific Advisory
0              NaN  Irrigate the crop if there is no sufficient mo...
1              NaN  Borer spray insecticide like Carbaryl 50 WP @ ...
2              NaN  250ml/acre. If the attack of Fall Army worm is...
3              NaN  for effective control of this insects or use p...
4            MAIZE  म ा के खेत म पया  नमी न होने पर फसल की िसंचाई ...
5              NaN  िलए काब रल 50 डूपी @ 1 िकलो ाम / एकड़ की दर स...
6              NaN  िमली / एकड़ दर से िछड़काव कर। यिद फ़ॉल आम  कीड...
7              NaN  भावी िनयं ण के िलए नीिमसाईड का िछड़काव कर या फ...
8              NaN  Irrigate the crop if there is no sufficient mo...
9              NaN  cutworm apply Carbaryl 50% WP @ 800g in 800 li...
10             NaN  76% EC@ 112-150ml in 200-400 liters of water/a...
11             NaN  apply Chlorpyriphos 20% EC @ 3- 4 ml/kg seed a...
12           WHEAT  गें की फसल म पया  नमी न होने पर फसल की िसंचाई...
13             NaN  िलए काब रल 50% WP @ 800 ाम को 800 लीटर पानी / ...
14             NaN  @ 112-150 िम.ली. को 200-400 लीटर पानी / एकड़ क...
15             NaN  दीमक को िनयंि त करने के िलए ोरपायरीफॉस 20% ईसी...
16             NaN                                      म िछड़काव कर।
17             NaN  Farmers are advised to apply N.P.V @ 250 L.E p...
18             NaN  at the time of grain formation in pigeonpea/gr...
19          BENGAL  cut worm then apply chlorpyriphos 20 EC @ 2 ml...
20           GRAM/  िकसानो ंको सलाह दी जाती है की चना एवं मसूर म द...
21       CHICK PEA  िनयं ण के िलए N.P.V @ 250 L.E ित हेेयर दर से ...
22             NaN  कटुआ कीड़ा का कोप अिधक हो तो ोरपायरीफॉस 20 ईसी...
23             NaN                   घोल बनाकर जड़ के पास िछड़काव कर।
24             NaN  Keeping in view of relative humidity farmers a...
25             NaN  crop against attack of white rust. If infectio...
26             NaN  2 gram/ litre of water is advised. Monitoring ...
27             NaN  bug and aphid is advised. Rogor 30 EC at the r...
28         MUSTARD  of water are quite effective in controlling th...
29             NaN  सापेि क आ ता को ान म रखते ए िकसानो ंको सलाह दी...
30             NaN  िनगरानी करते रह। यिद सं मण अिधक है तो Dithane-...
31             NaN  बनाकर िछड़काव करे। मा  या एिफड को िनयंि त करने...
32             NaN                 लीटर पानी म घोल बनाकर िछड़काव करे
```

it is making a different row for each new line in `crop Specific Advisory`
how to merge these rows,
I can say that there is something in English when a new entry comes

Answer (score 0):

You can first use `fillna` and combine it with a groupby.

```
df = df.fillna(method='ffill')
df.groupby('Crop(Varieties)')['Crop Specific Advisory'].apply(lambda x: "%s" % ''.join(x))
```

The `fillna` with `ffill` replace the NaN with the word above ('forward fill') and the groupby simply combines all the rows of each crop into a single string.

Input:

```
   Crop(Varieties) Crop Specific Advisory
0         MUSTARD                       a
1              NaN                      b
2              NaN                      c
3              NaN                      d
4            MAIZE                      e
5              NaN                      f
6              NaN                      g
7            WHEAT                      h
8              NaN                      i
9              NaN                      j
10             NaN                      k
11             NaN                      l
12          BENGAL                      m
13             NaN                      n
14             NaN                      o
15             NaN                      p
```

output:

```
                Crop Specific Advisory
Crop(Varieties)
BENGAL                            mnop
MAIZE                              efg
MUSTARD                           abcd
WHEAT                            hijkl
```